# Inserting multiple arrays into different rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm collecting input fields as an array to be inserted into the different rows in the database. However it only inserts the first row of the array.

Please kindly assist. I have some issues handling arrays. I don't know how to construct the query and I've tried to search online and I couldn't get enough help. I'll really appreciate help with the query.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type = "text" class = "form_element" name = "wat_office_type[]" />
<input type = "number" name = "wat_office_price[]" class = "form_element" />
```

while I use jQuery to add more input boxes.

Here is my php:

```
$wat_office_type_post = $_POST['wat_office_type'];
$wat_office_price_post = $_POST['wat_office_price'];
$wat_office_type = array();
$wat_office_price = array();

foreach ($wat_office_type_post as $type) {
    if (!empty($type))
        $wat_office_type[] = $afrisoft->antiHacking($type);
}

foreach ($wat_office_price_post as $post) {
    if (!empty($post))
        $wat_office_price[] = $afrisoft->antiHacking($post);
}
```

I want to insert into 2 separate rows and achieve something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Pk | wat_office_type  | wat_office_price |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | executive office |             1000 |
--------------------------------------------
| 2  | Training room    |             4000 |
--------------------------------------------
| 3  | Events room      |             5000 |
--------------------------------------------
```

I'll kindly appreciate if I can get help with the `insert` query (mysql,php) on how I can insert all values of the first array in one column, and values of the second array into the second column, while each are matching `d` numbers of arrays supplied.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to combine the two arrays into something like

```
$list = array(
 array('pk' => 1, 'type' => 'executive', 'price' => 1000),
 array('pk' => 2, 'type' => 'training room', 'price' => 4000),
 array('pk' => 3, 'type' => 'events room', 'price' => 5000)
);
```

then you can call a foreach loop to query the database with each element, like

```
foreach($list as $key => $value) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (pk, type, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$params = array($value['pk'], $value['type'], $value['price']);
  if($query->execute($params)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }  
}
```

so instead doing two foreach loops and putting results in different arrays, you could use one foreach loop and create an associative array for each set of results (I assume the count on both of your arrays is the same?) as I mentioned above.